# Is there a way to mirror ipad pro screen to ubuntu?

Tags: apple, ipad, airplay

I have tried the solution of use this [totem plugin](https://github.com/phuang/totem-plugin-airplay). But it does not seem to work for me due to this [problem](https://github.com/phuang/totem-plugin-airplay/issues/1).

I did some Google search and could not find a solution, even a commercial one.